# Why is my Cursor not closed in an Android Activity?

Tags: android, database, android-cursor

In my Android Activity I need to read things from a database.  I've created a helper class which deals with my database access.  This helper class has several different methods designed to read different things and return them without much fuss.  Here is one example.

```
public String GetName(int id)
{
    String toReturn = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try
    {
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] {"name"},
            "id = " + id,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

        assert(cursor.getCount() == 1);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        toReturn = new String(cursor.getString(0)); 
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

I keep getting the error

> 10-10 15:52:18.991: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(28313): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE id = 0
>   10-10 15:52:18.991: W/SQLiteCompiledSql(28313): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

with a stack trace that leads right to this function (and ones very similar to it), although the Activity works fine.  What am I doing wrong?  I looked around here for a while, and that's when I added the try/finally to make sure I always close the Cursor, but I'm still getting the error.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you take the `assert` out?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would make a difference, but it doesn't regardless.

Comment: I thought it may prevent the `finally` from executing. Stranger things have happened. What if you put a log after `.close()`? Does it fire?

Comment: Yes.  If I put a log after close (inside the cursor != null if) then I see the message.

Comment: Try logging whether or not the `Cursor` closes after you've called close. `if(cursor.isClosed())`, then log. Perhaps you have it opened elsewhere in your app. On a side note, it's not necessary to call `new String()`.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, if anyone's curious I also get one close log message each time the function is called (verified by logging when it's called).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion aneal.  Implementing it results in verification that the Cursor is closed.  I don't think that I have it opened elsewhere in the app, as that's the only place I run that particular query (making it just a one line function call is why I have this helper class in the first place) and the stack trace points to this function.

Comment: I think no one has answered my question because it is no longer easily visible and no one who knows has seen it.  It could be that my last comment left a mistaken impression however, so let me correct that.  While 'cursor.isClosed()' returns 'true' I am still getting the error.  I'd still like to know what, if anything, I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is this happening in a multithreaded environment?  Is it possible your database instance is being closed or overwritten in another thread?

Comment: The application is multi-threaded, but access to the database which is causing the problem only happens in the main (UI) thread, I believe.  Most access takes place in UI callbacks, the rest during Activity life cycle callbacks. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) is why I believe that all that takes place in one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing cursor correctly but you also need to close the database, make sure that you are closing the database also:

```
if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
```

Comment: Yup, this is it.  I had seen the "...or database object..." in the error message and had made sure I closed my database too, but before I told you you were wrong I double checked.  Turns out I had opened the database in both `onCreate` and `onResume`.  Fixing this got rid of the very misleading error message.  Thanks for helping me figure out what actually caused it.